# Transfer Smart Capture Form to Code View in Cloud Pages

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, smart-capture

Is it possible to transfer a smart capture form that was created in content builder over to a code view marketing cloud page? I essentially want to move it to custom code, but I cannot figure out how to do so and keep the function of adding form completes to a data extension.

Comment: There's no way to just move the whole thing, you would have to copy and paste bit by bit. What in particular is the reason why you want to do this? If it's for adding some additional actions in AMPscript, you can easily do it in thein HTML view, or even better - create your own form from scratch.

Comment: I am not all that familiar with AMPscript, so I was trying to find an easy way to take advantage of Smart Capture. Basically, I already have a page built in Code View and all we have to do is change the form to feed to a Marketing Cloud DE. (Currently it is a Web-to-lead form for Sales Cloud).

Comment: @psfraga: If you are migrating from a Web to Lead form I suspect you will be using the new form to collect lead/contact data and send emails from marketing cloud. If you still intend to write the data to Sales Cloud you should reconsider your approach. A subscriber sent an email directly from the data extension will be written to the Subscriber List in Marketing Cloud (often with email address as Subscriber Key). After it is also written to Sales Cloud it will likely sync to Marketing Cloud via synced data sources. This will create another instance of the contact with the Salesforce Id as key.

Comment: As result you will have a duplicate record that you cannot merge. Both will count against the contact limit and message history is disjointed (spread between the two records). A solution around this would be usage of Salesforce AMPScript functions to write the records to Sales Cloud and not to a data extension. The implementation is a bit more advanced but will be worth the effort.